# best apache server & mysql & php fpm configuration

Tags: php, mysql, multithreading, apache, whm

i read a lot and a lot about these topics , but i am unable to get something useful as i am not that expert

i am running a game that based on multi thread (mutex) on php using whm,
it works by locking a single table in db ,

if table = 1 , then it wont process request till it get back to = 0 again (after first thread finish )

my issue is that when there are over 100 players at same time are playing , each of them will normally make 10-40 requests to db per s

but when we have this amount of requests then a delay comes (up to 3 min) on order to processed each thread in order by id .. which is super slow ..

i got a vps server trying to make this better by getting good amount of rams and cpus,  but nothing changed ..

my code is :

```
public function processQueue($type = 3, $playerId = 0)
    {
        global $gameConfig;
        $this->load_model('Mutex', 'mutex');
        $this->mutex->releaseOnTimeout();
        if ($this->mutex->lock()) {
            $this->processTaskQueue($type, $playerId);
            // to make it weekly put "/2" after it 
            $row = db::get_row("SELECT gs.cur_week w1, CEIL((TO_DAYS(NOW())-TO_DAYS(gs.start_date))) w2 FROM g_settings gs");
            if (($row['w2'] - $row['w1']) >= 1) {
                db::query("UPDATE g_settings gs SET gs.cur_week=:cur", array(
                    'cur' => intval($row['w2'])
                ));
                $allP = db::get_all("SELECT p.id FROM p_players p WHERE p.total_people_count>500 ");
                $Ids2 = "";
                foreach($allP as $Ids)
                {
                    $Ids2 .= ($Ids2 == "" ) ? $Ids['id'] : ",".$Ids['id'];
                }
                $Ids2 = "(".$Ids2.")";
                db2::query("UPDATE p_players p SET p.gold_num=p.gold_num+:gold WHERE p.id IN $Ids2",array('gold' =>200));
                
                $this->setWeeklyMedals(intval($row['w2']));
            }
            $this->mutex->release();
        }
    }

// mutex lock 
define("__QS_LOCK_FS_", MODELS_DIR . "lock");
class Mutex_Model extends Model
{




    public function lock()
    {
        if (0 < db::count("UPDATE g_settings gs SET gs.qlocked=1, qlocked_date=NOW() WHERE gs.qlocked=0") && ($fp = fopen(__QS_LOCK_FS_, "r")) != FALSE) {
            if (flock($fp, LOCK_EX)) {
                fclose($fp);
                return TRUE;
            }
            fclose($fp);
        }
        return FALSE;
    }

    public function release()
    {
        $this->_releaseInternal();
        db::query("UPDATE g_settings gs SET gs.qlocked=0");
    }

    public function releaseOnTimeout()
    {
        if (0 < db::count("UPDATE g_settings gs SET \r\n\t\t\t\tgs.qlocked=0\r\n\t\t\tWHERE\r\n\t\t\t\tgs.qlocked=1\r\n\t\t\t\tAND\r\n\t\t\t\tTIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(NOW(), gs.qlocked_date)) > 120")) {
            $this->_releaseInternal();
        }
    }

    public function _releaseInternal()
    {
        if (($fp = fopen(__QS_LOCK_FS_, "r")) != FALSE) {
            flock($fp, LOCK_UN);
            fclose($fp);
        }
    }
```

server info :

Server Load 0.656738 (4 CPUs)
Memory Used 48.06% (3,755,752 of 7,814,064)
Swap Used   25.71% (1,040,692 of 4,048,572)

what i tried to do but didn't work :

- editing my.cnf
- changed apache configurations many times
- changed php fpm configurations many times
- changed mpm to perfork,event,worker

my current settings :

Start Servers [500]
Minimum Spare Servers [500]

Maximum Spare Servers [2000]

Server Limit  [5000]

5000
Max Request Workers [5000]

php fpm settings :

Max Requests : 55000 ( tried from 20 - 55000 random values )
Max Children : 10000 ( tried from 30 - 10000 random values )
Process Idle Timeout : 700 ( tried from 10 to 700 random values )

my my.cnf file :

```
[root@server ~]# cat /etc/my.cnf

# For advice on how to change settings please see
# http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-configuration-defaults.html

[mysqld]
disable-log-bin=1
default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
performance-schema=0
sql_mode=""
innodb_autoinc_lock_mode=2
binlog_format=row
transaction-isolation=READ-COMMITTED
#Slow queries configuration

slow_query_log = 1
slow-query_log_file = /var/log/mysql-slow.log
long_query_time = 2


#
# Remove leading # and set to the amount of RAM for the most important data
# cache in MySQL. Start at 70% of total RAM for dedicated server, else 10%.
# innodb_buffer_pool_size = 128M
#
# Remove leading # to turn on a very important data integrity option: logging
# changes to the binary log between backups.
# log_bin
#
# Remove leading # to set options mainly useful for reporting servers.
# The server defaults are faster for transactions and fast SELECTs.
# Adjust sizes as needed, experiment to find the optimal values.
# join_buffer_size = 128M
# sort_buffer_size = 2M
# read_rnd_buffer_size = 2M
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock

# Disabling symbolic-links is recommended to prevent assorted security risks
symbolic-links=0

log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
innodb_buffer_pool_size=30G
max_allowed_packet=568435456
open_files_limit=500000
# innodb_file_per_table=1
bind-address=127.0.0.1
mysqlx=0
max_connections=100000
```

i am sorry i wrote a lot , i am not expert at all and i am trying my best , i promise i read alot and a lot before writing nothing works for me , what i need is make the threads process faster to finish pleayers queues without delay

//EDIT ADDING MAIN QUERIES WORKING IN LOCK

```
public function processTaskQueue($type, $playerId)
    {
     
        $result = db::get_all("SELECT  q.id, q.player_id, q.village_id, q.to_player_id, q.to_village_id, q.proc_type, q.building_id, q.proc_params, q.threads, q.execution_time, TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, NOW(),q.end_date) remainingTimeInSeconds FROM p_queue q WHERE TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, NOW(),(q.end_date - INTERVAL (q.execution_time*(q.threads-1)) SECOND)) <= 0  ORDER BY TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, NOW(),(q.end_date - INTERVAL (q.execution_time*(q.threads-1)) SECOND)) ASC");
        foreach ($result as $resultRow) {
            $remain = $resultRow['remainingTimeInSeconds'];
            if ($remain < 0) {
                $remain = 0;
            }
             $resultRow['threads_completed_num'] = $resultRow['execution_time'] <= 0 ? $resultRow['threads'] : floor(($resultRow['threads'] * $resultRow['execution_time'] - $remain) / $resultRow['execution_time']);
            if ($this->processTask($resultRow)) {
                unset($result);
                $this->processQueue($type, $playerId);
                break;
            }
        }
        unset($result);


    }

 public function processTask($taskRow)
    {
        $customAction = FALSE;
        switch ($taskRow['proc_type']) {
            case QS_ACCOUNT_DELETE:
                {
                    $this->deletePlayer($taskRow['player_id']);
                    break;
                }
            case QS_BUILD_CREATEUPGRADE:
                {
                    $customAction = $this->executeBuildingTask($taskRow);
                    break;
                }
            case QS_BUILD_DROP:
                {
                    $customAction = $this->executeBuildingDropTask($taskRow);
                    break;
                }
            case QS_TROOP_RESEARCH:
                {
                }
            case QS_TROOP_UPGRADE_ATTACK:
                {
                }
            case QS_TROOP_UPGRADE_DEFENSE:
                {
                    $this->executeTroopUpgradeTask($taskRow);
                    break;
                }
            case QS_TROOP_TRAINING:
                {
                    $this->executeTroopTrainingTask($taskRow);
                    break;
                }
            case QS_TROOP_TRAINING_HERO:
                {
                    $this->executeHeroTask($taskRow);
                    break;
                }
            case QS_TOWNHALL_CELEBRATION:
                {
                    $this->executeCelebrationTask($taskRow);
                    break;
                }
            case QS_MERCHANT_GO:
                {
                    $customAction = $this->executeMerchantTask($taskRow);
                    break;
                }
            case QS_MERCHANT_BACK:
                {
                    if ($taskRow['building_id'] >= 1) {
                        $this->returnMerchantTask($taskRow);
                    }
                    break;
                }
            case QS_WAR_REINFORCE:
                {
                }
            case QS_WAR_ATTACK:
                {
                }
            case QS_WAR_ATTACK_PLUNDER:
                {
                }
            case QS_WAR_ATTACK_SPY:
                {
                }
            case QS_CREATEVILLAGE:
                {
                    $customAction = $this->executeWarTask($taskRow);
                    break;
                }
            case QS_LEAVEOASIS:
                {
                    $this->executeLeaveOasisTask($taskRow);
                    break;
                }
            case QS_PLUS1:
                {
                    db::query('UPDATE p_players p SET p.active_plus_account=0 WHERE p.id=:id', array(
                        'id' => intval($taskRow['player_id'])
                    ));
                    break;
                }
            case QS_PLUS2:
                {
                    $this->executePlusTask($taskRow, 1);
                    break;
                }
            case QS_PLUS3:
                {
                    $this->executePlusTask($taskRow, 2);
                    break;
                }
            case QS_PLUS4:
                {
                    $this->executePlusTask($taskRow, 3);
                    break;
                }
            case QS_PLUS5:
                {
                    $this->executePlusTask($taskRow, 4);
                    break;
                }
            case QS_TATAR_RAISE:
                {
                    $this->load_model('Artefacts', 'A');
                    $this->A->createTatarVillages();
                    break;
                }
            case QS_SITE_RESET:
                {
                    $this->load_model('Install', 'm');
                    $this->m->processSetup($GLOBALS['SetupMetadata']['map_size']);
                    $customAction = TRUE;

                    break;
                }
            case QS_CROP_DELETE:
                {
                    $this->load_model('Crop', 'c');
                    $customAction = $this->c->deleteCrop($taskRow);
                    break;
                }
            case QS_ARTEFACTS_RAISE:
                {
                    $this->load_model('Artefacts', 'A');
                    $this->A->createArtefacts();
                    break;
                }
        }
        if (!$customAction) {
            $remaining_thread = $taskRow['threads'] - $taskRow['threads_completed_num'];
            if ($remaining_thread <= 0) {
                db::query("DELETE FROM p_queue WHERE id=:id", array(
                    'id' => intval($taskRow['id'])
                ));
            } else {
                db::query("UPDATE p_queue q SET q.threads=:th WHERE q.id=:id", array(
                    'th' => intval($remaining_thread),
                    'id' => intval($taskRow['id'])
                ));
            }
        }
        return $customAction;
    }
```

thanks a lot

Comment: Not something I've tried, but it may be the locking mechanism - try using something like semaphores instead which should be a lot more lightweight.

Comment: Just taking a quick look, it seems like the SQL logic could be moved to the database server as a stored procedure so that the database could handle any write locking, if necessary. It could return the `w2` value, too, or a subsequent SELECT could be issued.

Comment: I'm also not really sure why you are using both a file system lock as well as an artificial database lock? But regardless, you want to perform as little logic as possible inside of the lock, even if it means using multiple locks on the same request, if possible.

Comment: Thank you guys for your kind response ,can any help me fixing this ? even if you want me to pay for it .. i really suffered a lot ..

Comment: Using a database to implement a mutex is a poor choice. You are introducing significant processing for something that needs to be as fast as possible. A simple `flock()` would be better, or semaphores if your server supports them. You have other issues too: your queries are less than optimal. All this is slowing your system down.

Comment: If you're looking to pay someone there are sites that can put you in touch with freelancers, or check the profiles of contributors here: some are open to this sort of work.

Comment: This lock is antithetical to performance, and apparently you introduced it only to prevent some sort of logic bug.  You have gone completely down the wrong path.  Look at @RickJames answer.  Using InnoDB is a start.  You need a transactional engine.  But you also need to configure things like the innodb_buffer_pool_size, as he illustrated.  The amount of buffer pool memory should be around 3/4 of total server memory.  This might be a significant problem if you are trying to run everything on a single server.  Did you adjust the value?

Comment: Is the "lock" around `processTaskQueue`?  Might it be better to put it around `processTask`?  How long does the `SELECT` take?  (see PHP's `microtime(true)`)

Comment: Thanks for all of you guys ,i am really happy with your help .. i did make explain and converted the query as you said , this is the result id
select_type SIMPLE

table q 
partitions NULL
type index
possible_keys NULL
keyPRIMARY
key_len 8
ref NULL
rows 3526
filtered 33.33
Extra Using where
for the pt-query-digest , it says bash: pt-query-digest: command not found

Comment: @gview yes i tried edting these numbers but nothing becomes better at any point with them ,i already use innodb and i will read more about transactional hope something works

Comment: @Rick James the select is taking a long time , 962 total, Query took 0.0008 seconds , the system calls the first function that does the lock every time that a-visitor clicks on any page , and from this point it determines weather system can manage new threads on not

Comment: @Tangentially Perpendicular you wouldn't believe how many times i tried find someone on freelancer ,no one is able to understand my issue i made over 30 job posts there ..

Comment: 0.8 ms to get 952 rows?  Not bad.  Does each user click once a second?  Maybe it is cheaper to _optimistically assume_ you can start a new thread, rather than checking?  Maybe a simpler check can be performed _after_ starting the thread?

Comment: If the query you are talking about is the query of the p_queue table, that query is unable to use an index.  If you have a computation that involves a column you are then going to use in the WHERE clause, mysql can not use an index, and will table scan.   ` WHERE TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, NOW(),(q.end_date - INTERVAL (q.execution_time*(q.threads-1)) SECOND)) <= 0 `

Comment: See `percona.com` for the toolkit containing `pt-query-digest`

Comment: So if p_queue grows, the performance will degrade, however, the main issue is that you have serialized your entire game computation.   You need to go back to where you were before you started trying to put in the locking, and return to your logic.  Get the queries working, perhaps employing the new technique of SELECT FOR UPDATE.

Comment: I'm available; ontact me at mysql at rjweb dot org .

Comment: Is there only one row `g_settings` in `SELECT  gs.cur_week w1, CEIL((TO_DAYS(NOW())-TO_DAYS(gs.start_date))) w2
        FROM  g_settings gs`?

Comment: @Rick James normally users make up to 2-5 repeated queues per second , which all with have same end time and this what makes the issue of locking that it has to process all of these at once , but what it does is process them one by one and after each one create new lock as well .. and that cause a huge performance issue , the normal average of requests per one second is up to 300 in such games. , and i am checking now pt-query-digest . thanks a lot

Comment: @Rick James i contacted you

Comment: @gview it is a very famous script , called dboor twars , i took a look at many other scripts of same structure and they all are written in the same way , it is a very old script we are talking about something made in 2009 , i was able to reach to someone who has solved this in the past and he told me the fixing is in mysql , but he couldn't remember  how

Comment: @Rick James g_sesttings has only one row and 8 column(s)

Answer (score 1):

How long (in milliseconds) do you need to lock the table?

You *should* make sure the table is `ENGINE=InnoDB` and then use "transactions" instead of table locks.  If you are not already there, there is a 'learning curve' to get you there.  But, once you are there, you abandon the table locks and build *short* sets of SQL statements into transactions.

Each transaction will be "atomic".  That is, it does as mutex-like exclusion of other threads, but at the *row* level, not the *table* level.

Be sure to have suitable indexes on the table(s).

Be sure to use `FOR UPDATE` on `SELECTs` in the transactions (when needed).

If you need to "lock" something for more than a few seconds, you will need to rethink the locking mechanism.  (We need more details to help you with this.)

It is hard to "throw hardware" at a problem like yours.  While one thread has the 'table' locked, no other threads can touch that table -- thereby effectively leading to a single CPU core, etc.  By moving to "row locking" maybe more threads can have *different rows* locked at the same time.

Please provide the main queries that are run during a "lock".  We might be able to give you some more tips.

If you are switching from MyISAM to InnoDB on a 'server' with 8GB of ram:

```
key_buffer_size = 20M
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 5G
max_allowed_packet=80M
open_files_limit=5000
max_connections=500
```

You have been collecting data in the slowlog; use `pt-query-digest` to summarize it.  Then show us the first couple of queries.

If you have hundreds of users, do *not* set the Apache settings in the thousands.  It wastes memory.  8GB should be plenty, but not when it is unnecessarily allocated.

This is not "sargable":

```
WHERE TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, NOW(),
       (q.end_date - INTERVAL (q.execution_time*(q.threads-1)) SECOND))
       <= 0
```

Hence, it cannot use an index and that probably leads to a table scan.

I am not sure if this will help:

```
WHERE q.end_date <=
       NOW() + INTERVAL (q.execution_time*(q.threads-1)) SECOND
```

Please elaborate on the need for 3 columns in the test.

Swapping, especially if it is HDD, will hurt performance a lot.  My suggestions to `my.cnf` and Apache config are aimed at avoiding swapping.

What is the value of `Max_used_connections`?

Comment: Hi Rick , thanks a lot for you kind replay. i already use innoDB , tried to figure how to use transactions before but no lock i caused a lot of errors , i need the lock for the following reason : when a player make attack task for example with 5000 soldiers , without locking the table the soldiers become 10K (double) for some reason , i need locking till the query is executed to forbid this from happening .

Comment: @Zeyad - (I added more.)  Possibly a missing `FOR UPDATE`.

Comment: i added the quries in the post , thanks a lot . i will try these settings as well in my.cnf now . i really appreciate your help ..

Comment: I 2nd the advice here.  Make sure you understand mysql concurrency and what a select for update does.  A big reason to use InnoDB is to get row level locking which increases concurrency.  For every query you have, you should be running EXPLAIN query_sql, and evaluating the result.  You need to make sure you are covering all your where criteria as well as any joins with indexes that make sense.

Comment: value of Max_used_connections is 31 . my server is ssd , i tried editing my.cnf many many times with random values or coping from github (because i do not know how to calculate them ) but none worked and some stopped whole server from working ..

Comment: Right, because you are scattershotting your changes, hoping for a miracle.  That is not how you debug and fix problems.  You have to change one thing at a time, and have some understanding of what you are changing and why.  The InnoDB settings should be standard for you.  Set them and leave them be.  Don't change anything you don't understand.  That is basic  MySQL advice, not something to fix a design that will never perform acceptably.  Again, go back to what you stated previously, that you only started on the path because there was a bug or race condition you didn't understand.  Fix that.

Comment: 31 -- "max_connections=100000" is severe overkill (and wasting RAM).  Setting values too high can cause "crashes".

Comment: I agree with @gview .  I made a few obvious recommendations.  For a more thorough evaluation of _your_ `GLOBAL STATUS` and `VARIABLES`, see http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/mysql_analysis

Comment: `Memory Used 48.06% (3,755,752 of 7,814,064) Swap Used 25.71% (1,040,692 of 4,048,572)`  You can't afford in a system where you want realtime computation, to have any swapping going on.  Swapping is catastrophic for performance.